# discord pynacl issue pls

Tags: python, discord

```
 python main.py
WARNING:discord.client:PyNaCl is not installed, voice will NOT be supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/EpicBot/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    client = EpicBot()
  File "/home/runner/EpicBot/utils/bot.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.update_prefixes_db.start()
  File "/home/runner/EpicBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 398, in start
    self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 336, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f9c7e409b70>
```

i tried downloading python.discord.client package but still not working

Comment: How did you download your "said" package? Showing an error without context is not helpful, I don't know the steps you took to get there

Comment: @InfinityA.B.S did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

First, you need to install the `PyNaCl` library in order to use the voice features. Run this command:

```
pip install -U discord.py
```

Then, in your application you have to close the connection at the end. In relation to your code, you can do it either manually:

```
session.close()
```

or with contextManger that close the session itself:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```